# How to set up event listener for a particular div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation, event-listener

I am creating a div that takes in the value from the input and this div contains a done button that I want to use to clear the current node and it's parent. I am using an event listener to the done variable which is created every time the add function is invoked but my problem is that the eventlistener automatically fires every time the add function is called.

```
        <div>
        <form method="post" action="/">
        <input  class="inputCls" type="text" name="item" id="input"  />
        <div class="addCls" onclick="add()" style="cursor:pointer">Add</div>
        </form>
                <script>        

                 function add() {
                        var inpElem = document.getElementById('input');
                        var doneElem = document.createElement('div');   
                        var divElem = document.createElement('div');
                        var done = document.createElement('div');   

                        if(inpElem.value == '') {

                            return false;
                            inpElem.value;
                        }
                        else {
                        document.body.appendChild(divElem);                      
                        divElem.className = 'alert';
                        divElem.innerHTML = inpElem.value;                      
                        divElem.appendChild(done);                  
                        done.className = "doneBtn"; 
                        done.innerHTML = "Done";

                         /*creating the closing button */
                        done.addEventListener("click",close(),false);
                        }

                }


                function close() {
                    alert('yaay');
                    /*removeChild(this.parentNode);*/
                }
        </script>
```

How should I add the eventListener?

Comment: divElem.innerHTML = input.value;   what is input ?

Comment: Its undefined in your code

Comment: The text appears inside the new div but it also fires the eventlistener

Comment: oh..i i must have copied the wrong code..let me change it

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K86d6/1/

Comment: Its working as expected it seems

Comment: I added () to the function invocation